Are there two equations with nothing strictly between them, but at least one quasi-equation between them?
Consider the signature of a single binary operation $+$, and consider the set $Eq$ of all equations in that signature, and also consider the set $Qeq$ of all quasi-equations in that signature. I define a strict partial order $<$ over $Eq$, such that $E < E'$ precisely when $E'$ implies $E$ but is not implied by $E$. Of course, the same definition can be applied to $Qeq$. Are there two equations $E$ and $E'$, such that $E < E'$ and there is no equation $E''$ strictly between $E$ and $E'$, but there is at least one quasi-equation $Q$ between them? If so, can someone give me an example of such $E$, $E'$ and $Q$? If not, can someone prove it?

Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/480132/are-there-two-equations-with-no-equation-strictly-between-them-but-at-least-one

Is equation the same as identity? Also, what is a quasi-equation?
